# How to Share a QGIS Project

Tags: qgis

I want to share my QGIS project to someone else who also uses QGIS, how would I do this? I am very new to QGIS and am not very tech savvy.

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/is-there-an-automatic-function-in-qgis-to-package-all-files-in-a-project-for-tra

Comment: So I was able to save my project as a .qgs and sent it to the other person. They were able to open it, but the delimited layers wouldn't open for him. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

A possibility is to save the project and all files (layers) to the same Geopackage file and send this.

As this sometimes can be a bit tricky, an even easier way is to create a zip folder containing project and data. See an example here: https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/kAXbCLWneg91kWY ( I used it today for this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/384194/88814). Unzip the folder, than open the project.

Be sure the have all files in the same folder or at least keep the same folder hierarchy whan saving as in the local project and activate rekative path in the settings. Otherwise, the files will not be found.

Always copy **all** files in the zip or Geopackage folder, not just the QGIS project (.qgz or .qgs files) - see here as well: [Reordering layers in GeoPackage and changing the default naming in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329427/reordering-layers-in-geopackage-and-changing-the-default-naming-in-qgis). As you see in the screenshot, I added the project file + 5 Geopackage files and packed all together to a zip file:

[image]

Comment: So I tried the Geopackage, but how would the other person use it? Would they open the destination GeoPackage link that I send them? I'm not exactly sure how it works on the other persons end

Comment: So I was able to save my project as a .qgs and sent it to the other person. They were able to open it, but the delimited layers wouldn't open for him. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: You must always send all the files that contain the data od the layers together with the project. In the project, the data itself is not saved. Will come back later with an answer to your question about Geopackage.

Comment: The Geopackage must be opened in QGIS. In the QGIS file browser, you can inspect the Geopackage and it's content. If you have a project saved in the Geopackage file, click `Menu Project / Open From / Geopackage`. For the zip see updated answer